# Unable to remove tr in a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

so I am having a problem in removing a particular tr in table using jquery.

So this is the scenario:

I have a table in which rows where clickable. And when I clicked one of them, I will be able to update the object data associated with that row. However, after updating the object, I want to reflect the changes in the td's of that particular tr.

My solution is, to remove the old tr and replace with the new tr. However, It did not remove the old tr instead just inserted the new tr. So this is my code:

```
   function update_table_after_updating(selected_violator){
            violators_table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
                var tr = ($(this));
                var td_text = $(this).find('td:first').text();      
                if(td_text == selected_violator.violator_id){
                    console.log(tr);
                   //I cant remove this row
                    tr.remove();
                    return false;
                }
            });
            update_table(selected_violator);
        }
```

The update_table() function

```
function update_table(violator){
        var img_str1 = '<img class=\"obj-pic\" src=\"' + Main.Vars.base_path + violator.front_temp_file_path + '\">';
        var img_str2 = '<img style=\"margin-left: 10px;\" class=\"obj-pic\" src=\"' + Main.Vars.base_path + violator.rear_temp_file_path + '\">';
        var img_str3 = '<img style=\"margin-left: 10px;\" class=\"obj-pic\" src=\"' + Main.Vars.base_path + violator.right_temp_file_path + '\">';
        var img_str4 = '<img style=\"margin-left: 10px;\" class=\"obj-pic\" src=\"' + Main.Vars.base_path + violator.left_temp_file_path + '\">';

        violators_table.dataTable().fnAddData([
            violator.violator_id,
            violator.get_full_name(),
            'Under Construction',
            img_str1 + img_str2 + img_str3 + img_str4,
        ]);
        $('#violators_tbl tbody tr').on('click', function(){
            var td = $(this).find('td:first').text();
            //returns violator object
            selected_violator = get_violator(td);   
            show_modal('view_violator');
        });
    }
```

Thank you very much! Your responses will be greatly appreciated.

PS: I am using jquery DataTables.

Comment: can u create small example [http://plnkr.co/ ] (plnkr)

Answer (score 1):

Well this is kinda disappointing, I have searched through Jquery Docs then I have find this:

> .empty() ->  This method removes not only child (and other descendant)
>   elements, but also any text within the set of matched elements. This
>   is because, according to the DOM specification, any string of text
>   within an element is considered a child node of that element. Consider
>   the following HTML:

Unlike remove(). empty() also removes child nodes of the selected element.

And, voila! The tr has been removed.

Comment: that is quite a discovery I must say!